# .subscribe({ next: (result) => { this.newData = result.Items; }. what is next here

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm not sure what is next in the callback function

```
.subscribe({
       next: (result) => {
         this.newData = result.Items;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a callback that runs everytime the observable that you are attaching this `subscribe` to, is emitting a new value.

It becomes very clear in this example:

```
let observer;
let observable = new Observable(o => observer = o);
observable.subscribe({
  next: itm => console.log("New item", itm); //Callback #1
  error: e => console.error("Something went wrong: ", e), //Callback #2
  complete: lastValue => console.log(`Observable terminated with last value`:, lastValue); //Callback #3
});

observer.next(1); //Triggers Callback #1,
observer.next("foo"); //Triggers Callback #2
observer.error("Problem"); //Triggers Callback #2
observer.complete(); // Terminates the observable, no more calls to next possible
```

Comment: I don’t think the complete callback receives a value.